# Есть ли в Qt в QRegExp позиционные проверки?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt, qt5, qregexp

Вот такие вот проверки:

```
(?<=) - слева совпадает
(?<!) -  слева несовпадает
(?=) - справа совпадает
(?!) - справа несовпадает
```

Очень надо, но у меня не получается составить рабочее выражение, не находит. Нигде ничего по этому вопросу не написано, примеров не нашел. Есть ли вообще там такая возможность? Если есть, напишите пожалуйста, простой пример или ссылку использования таких проверок.

Comment: :) А что вы вообще ищите и где?

Comment: Кстати, не "слева/справа (не) совпадает", а "**непосредственно** слева/справа (не) совпадает".

Comment: <title>Ищу</title>   QReqExp reg("(?<=<title>)[.]{0,10}(?=</title>)")

Comment: Ну вроде такого, но не работает

Comment: `[.]` - это символьный класс, который находит символ `.`. Вам нужен `QReqExp reg("(?<=<title>)[^<]{0,10}(?=</title>)")` / `QReqExp reg("(?<=<title>)[^<]+(?=</title>)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `QReqExp reg("(?<=<title>)[.]{0,10}(?=</title>)")` `[.]` — это символьный класс, который находит символ `.` (буквальная точка).

Вам нужен

```
QReqExp reg("(?<=<title>)[^<]{0,10}(?=</title>)")
```

или

```
QReqExp reg("(?<=<title>)[^<]+(?=</title>)")
```

Тут

- `(?<=<title>)` - место в строке, непосредственно следующее после `<title>`
- `[^<]{0,10}` - от 0 до 10 символов, отличных от `<` (`[^<]+`  - 1+ таких символов)
- `(?=</title>)` - место в строке, непосредственно перед `</title>`.

В Qt5 действительно лучше использовать `QRegularExpression`, использующий регулярные выражения **PCRE**.

Ещё можно переписать выражение с использованием *захватывающей группы* вместо блоков предварительного просмотра вперёд и назад:

```
(?i)<title>([^<]+)</title>
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pknqea/1). Круглые скобки формируют захватывающую группу, доступ к которой осуществляется с помощью `match.captured(1)`.

Пример на Qt с использованием *захватывающей группы*:

```
QString s = "More <title>Super title</title> text More <title>Super title 2</title> text";
QRegularExpression reg = QRegularExpression("(?i)<title>([^<]+)</title>");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = reg.globalMatch(s);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    qDebug() << match.captured(1);
}
```

PS: `(?i)` = [`QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#PatternOption-enum).

Comment: Спс, получилось но с классом  QRegularExpression re. Наверно напишу код уже а вам + поставлю, хотя и на правильный ответ тоже сойдет

Comment: @MadokaMagica Я добавил код и немного изменил шаблон.

Answer (score 2):

`QRegExp` является чрезвычайно ограниченным и устаревшим классом, используйте [`QRegularExpression`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html), который поддерживает регулярные выражением в той мере, в какой их поддерживает Perl.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось только с классом QRegularExpression.  Пишу код:

```
QString str = "<title>Ищу<</title>";
    QRegularExpression re("(?<=<title>).+(?=</title>)",QRegularExpression::MultilineOption);
   //(?<=<title>)[^<]+(?=</title>) это регулярное выр. тоже работает
      QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(str);
      if (match.hasMatch()) {
          QString matched = match.captured(0);
          qDebug() <<"matched="<<matched;  //matched= "Ищу<"
      }
```